# Create multiple folders each with a file of the same name in terminal

Tags: terminal, directory, mkdir

Is it possible to do something like:

mkdir -p {folder1, folder2, folder3...}/

and then do something after the '/' like 'touch' to create an index.vue file in each folder simultaneously?

Comment: You can create many directories in a single command and touch/create many files, but not in the same command.

Comment: But you could do `mkdir folder{1..3}` and then `touch folder{1..3}/file`